# Save data to Collection and Display using MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have my `Model` class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
My View has 5 `TextBox`, 2 `Button` and a `ListView` to display grid.
In my `ViewModel` I was previously adding default values to the `ObservableCollection` of my `Model` class and displaying it to a `ListView`.

The button implementation is done using `ICommand` and `RelayCommand`.

Now I want to add data to the `ObservableCollection` from the user from the UI `TextBox`. How can I achieve that? The UI `TextBox` hasbindings with properties of the `Model` class.

My `View`

```
<ListView Name="UserGrid" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4,178,12,13"  ItemsSource="{Binding UserDatas}"  >
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,7,0,0" Name="txtUserId" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding UserId}" />
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,35,0,0" Name="txtFirstName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
```

Like these there are 5 TextBoxes

The `Model` class:

```
public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int userId;
    private string firstName;


public int UserId
    {
        get
        {
            return userId;
        }
        set
        {
            userId = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("UserId");
        }
    }
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
public class UsersViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<User> userDatas;

    public ObservableCollection<User> UserDatas
    {
        get
        {
            if (userDatas == null)
            {
                userDatas = new ObservableCollection<User>();
            }
            return userDatas;
        }
        set
        {
            userDatas = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("UserDatas");
        }
    }
```

}

```
   private CommandBase _LoadCommand;
   public ICommand LoadCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._LoadCommand == null)
                this._LoadCommand = new CommandBase(LoadData);
            return this._LoadCommand;
        }
    }

   private void LoadData(object obj)
   {
        //What need to be done here to access the textboxes of UI which are binded to User.cs class.

       User newUser = new User();
       UserDatas.Add(newUser);
   }
```

Now what I need to write in the LoadData method to take inputfrom textboxes from UI and store it in my `ObservableCollection`

Comment: Make use of Inotifypropertychanged. Now create a getter setter string for the textbox and bind it. Now once you have inputted value add it to your observable collection and it should reflect.

Comment: You shouldn't bind your model to the UI, as the UI should be agnostic of the model and only know about the viewmodel

Comment: What do you have so far? Can you show basically how you've bound your properties on your view/viewmodel?

Comment: My Model and ViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged and the in the MainWindow.xaml the ListView is bound to ObservableCollection of Model class.

Comment: I have added my bits and pieces of code please review.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you can do. Most obvious, is to have a "Add New" Command, which creates a new empty object and stores it in a `CurrentUser` or `SelectedUser` property.

This property is bound to the Template's (or Form's) context. You'd have 3 commands (Add New  User, Save User, Cancel to cancel addition of a new user creation).

For example

```
public class UsersViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public UsersViewModel() 
    {
        UserDatas = new ObservableCollection<User>();

        AddNewUserCommand = new RelayCommand(AddNewUser, param => !this.IsNewUser);
        SaveUserCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveUser);
        CancelNewUserCommand = new RelayCommand(CancelNewUser, param => this.IsNewUser);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<User> userDatas;
    public ObservableCollection<User> UserDatas
    {
        get { return userDatas; }
        set
        {
            userDatas = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("UserDatas");
        }
    }

    private User selectedUser;
    public User SelectedUser 
    {
        get { return selectedUser; }
        set
        {
            selectedUser = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedUser");
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsNewUser");
        }
    }

    public bool IsNewUser 
    {
        get 
        {
            if(SelectedUser==null)
                return false;

            return SelectedUser.UserId == 0;
        }
    }

    public ICommand AddNewUserCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand CancelNewUserCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand SaveUserCommand { get; private set; }

    private void AddNewUser() 
    {
        SelectedUser = new User();
    }

    private void SaveUser() 
    {
        // Just in case of concurency
        var newUser = SelectedUser;
        if(newUser == null) 
        {
            return;
        }

        var isNewUser = newUser.UserId == 0;

        // Persist it to the database
        this.userRepository.Add(newUser);
        this.userRepository.SaveChanges();

        // If all worked well, add it to the observable collection
        if(isNewUser) 
        {
            // Only add if new, otherwise it should be already in the collection
            UserDatas.Add(newUser)
        }
    }
}
```

But again, it's very discouraged to work directly on the model and bind it to the View. You should also create a ViewModel for your User and put validation (implement the `IDataErrorInfo` interface on the `UserViewModel`) in there and handling of state, for example tracking if the `UserViewModel` is dirty (i.e. data was changed).

All these are presentation concerns and not business logic, so they belong to a ViewModel and not to the Model itself.